# Radio Button not working - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, django

Hi Am using angularJS in my project. But when tried to add a span to one of my input field, all the radio buttons related to that became non-functioning. Can someone suggest me what's wrong here.

```
<tr ng-repeat="(k,v) in final_data.checks">
    <td>
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg" style="width:350%">
            <span class="input-group-addon">Check{{ k+ 1 }}</span>

            <input type="text" ng-model="v.check_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Add Check here">
        </div>
    </td>
    <!--<---->

    <td align="center">
        <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="radio" ng-model="v.category" name="{{ k }}" value="A">
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="radio" ng-model="v.category" name="{{ k }}" value="B">
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="radio" ng-model="v.category" name="{{ k }}" value="C">
    </td>
    <!--<button ng-click="clear()">Clear</button>-->

    <!--&ndash;&gt;-->
    <td>
        <br/>
        <a href="" ng-click="clear($index)">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding your new radio button out side the radio button group.
so when you add the new radio button the newly added button works but due to that it will affect your existing radio button.

Answer (score 0):

The div is actually affecting all parts here, because i type in something weird like 350%. I removed that part and added `<input type="text" ng-model="v.check_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Add Check here" style="width:100%">` instead. Now its working. Thanks Rajan